# pgpool shm_exit(0)

Tags: linux, centos, centos5, postgresql

I'm trying to set up pgpool-II on centos-5.4
For whatever reason pgpool-II fails silently when I try to start it up.
I can't seem to find a log file in the default /tmp dir or in /var/log.
Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ pgpool -a /etc/pool_hba.conf -f /etc/pgpool.conf -F /etc/pcp.conf -d
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: listen_addresses
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '*' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: port
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 9999 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: pcp_port
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 9898 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: socket_dir
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '/tmp' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: pcp_socket_dir
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '/tmp' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: backend_socket_dir
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '/tmp' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: pcp_timeout
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 10 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: num_init_children
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 32 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: max_pool
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 4 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: child_life_time
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 300 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: connection_life_time
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 0 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: child_max_connections
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 0 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: client_idle_limit
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 0 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: authentication_timeout
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 60 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: logdir
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '/tmp' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: pid_file_name
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '/var/run/pgpool/pgpool.pid' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: replication_mode
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: load_balance_mode
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: replication_stop_on_mismatch
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: replication_stop_on_mismatch: 0
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: failover_if_affected_tuples_mismatch
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: failover_if_affected_tuples_mismatch: 0
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: replicate_select
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: replicate_select: 0
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: reset_query_list
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 'ABORT; DISCARD ALL' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: extract_string_tokens: token: ABORT
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: extract_string_tokens: token:  DISCARD ALL
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: white_function_list
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: black_function_list
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 'nextval,setval' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: extract_string_tokens: token: nextval
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: extract_string_tokens: token: setval
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: print_timestamp
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: true kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: master_slave_mode
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: master_slave_sub_mode
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 'slony' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: delay_threshold
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 0 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: log_standby_delay
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 'none' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: connection_cache
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: true kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: health_check_timeout
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 20 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: health_check_period
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 0 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: health_check_user
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 'nobody' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: failover_command
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: failback_command
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: fail_over_on_backend_error
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: true kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: insert_lock
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: true kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: ignore_leading_white_space
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: true kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: log_statement
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: log_per_node_statement
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: log_connections
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: log_hostname
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: parallel_mode
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: enable_query_cache
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: pgpool2_hostname
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: system_db_hostname
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 'localhost' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: system_db_port
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 5432 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: system_db_dbname
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 'pgpool' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: system_db_schema
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 'pgpool_catalog' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: system_db_user
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 'postgres' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: system_db_password
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: enable_pool_hba
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: recovery_user
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 'nobody' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: recovery_password
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: recovery_1st_stage_command
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: recovery_2nd_stage_command
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: recovery_timeout
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 90 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: client_idle_limit_in_recovery
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 0 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: lobj_lock_table
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: '' kind: 4
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: ssl
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: false kind: 1
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: key: debug_level
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: value: 0 kind: 2
2011-08-18 14:01:56 DEBUG: pid 9267: shmem_exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like correct output.  Did you check your processes to make sure it wasn't running?

If you want to show pgpool log messages, you pass -n option to pgpool command:

```
pgpool -n -d > /tmp/pgpool.log 2>&1 &
```